# Why is creating a MSSQL(Express) database with Entity Framework so slow?

Tags: sql-server, database, performance, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

We are developing a WPF application which can manage multiple clients. For each client we need a separate database (within the same SQL Server instance). So we need a „create database“ more than once. All individual client-databases will have all the same database structure.

We use Entity Framework Version 6.1.3, code-first and a local installation of SQL Server 2014 Express. In our „real“ business-application a new database with about 60 tables is created properly, but the performance is not so good.

Trying to isolate the problem I wrote a small sample program which creates 5 databases in a loop, 1 table per database. On my Dev-PC (Windows 10, i7-6700 3.40GHz, 16 GB RAM) the executiontime for those 5 databases is about 1 minute  (11-12 secs for each database). When I debug the application, I see that there is a long wait on the line

```
dbContext.Database.CreateIfNotExists();
```

In SQL Server Profiler I see that it takes about 10 seconds per loop until the first entry arrives.

Any idea's where the time is lost? Or other suggestions for creating many databases (> 20) with the same DbContext in Entity Framework?

Here the source-code of my sample application:.

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System;

namespace TestEnityFramework01.Model
{
    [Table("Table01")]
    public class Table01        {
        [Key]
        [Column("ID", Order = 0, TypeName = "int")]
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [Column("Number01", TypeName = "int")]
        public int Number01 { get; set; }

        [Column("Date01")]
        public DateTime? Date01 { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        [Column("Text01", TypeName = "nvarchar")]
        public string Text01 { get; set; }

        [Column("Amount01")]
        public decimal Amount01 { get; set; }

        [Column("Doule01")]
        public double Doule01 { get; set; }

        [Column("Bool01")]
        public bool Bool01 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And the context:

```
using TestEnityFramework01.Model;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace TestEnityFramework01.Context 
{
    class ContextA : DbContext
    {
    public DbSet<Table01> Tabel01 { get; set; }

    public ContextA()
        : base("ContextA")
    {
        // Don't create database automatically
        Database.SetInitializer<ContextA>(null);
    }

    public ContextA(string pConnectionString)
            : base(pConnectionString)
        {
            // Don't create database automatically
            Database.SetInitializer<ContextA>(null);

            this.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
            this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
            this.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
    }
}
```

The test program produces in a loop five databases:

```
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    int _randomNumber = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        // create random number between 1 and 100'000
        _randomNumber = new Random().Next(1, 100000);

        // concat the random number to the database name
        string _databaseName = "DatabaseCustomer" + _randomNumber.ToString();

           // the connection-string look like this:
           // "Data Source=MyPC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MyDatabaseName;User ID=MyUser;Password=MyPassword;Integrated Security=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;"            
        string  _connectionString = GetConnectionString(_databaseName);

        using (var dbContext = new ContextA(_connectionString))
        {
            // create the database
            dbContext.Database.CreateIfNotExists();
        }
    }
}
```

**** UPDATE 16.06.2016**** 
When I switch the DB connection from SQL-Server 2014 Express to „SQL Server Compact Edition“, the creationtime for all 5 databases is about 1 or 2 seconds. Could it be that i use a wrong connectionstring to connect with the sql-server or my SQL-Server 2014 Express is not configured properly?

Comment: Out of curiosity, how big are the .mdf and .ldf files you're creating?  Seems default should be 3 meg and 1 meg, but how big are they in your test case?

Comment: The .mdf-File are 4'288 KB and the .ldf-Files are 1072 KB big.

Comment: Are you sure about the placement of `Database.SetInitializer<ContextA>(null);` in your code?  It seems naively glancing at the code that you're setting the database initializer inside of the initializer which seems wrong (possibly a recursive issue).  In examples online I'm seeing the setInitializer happen in a configuration section of the code.

Comment: Yes I think so. I can disable the line. Then the default setting is "CreateDatabaseIfNotExist ". But the performance still remains equally bad.

Comment: We have seen similar 10 second delays caused by SqlClient's own connection resiliency feature kicking in when EF tries to check if database exists by attempting to connect to it. If this is causing the delay in your scenario, you should be able to improve things by adding ConnectRetryCount=0 to the connection string.

Comment: Yes you are right. By adding ConnectRetryCount=0 to the connection string is about ten times faster. 
Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

This is because the code first Approach creates a new database and establishes connection with it.

I Think you should use sql query for Creating Database.

If You Want I can help you how will you do it with better UI and Functionality design

Please reply for my answer.

Comment: I want to not only create a new database, but also the database structure (tables) based on my code first model. And that, if possible with entity framework.

Comment: You can write your structure in txtFile and Create a sql Coomand run that command try it...... I think it will give you much better performance.

Comment: but If you want then you can use only entitiy framework its all upto you